# How to set a default TZ for django admin portal only?

Tags: django, django-admin

The TIME_ZONE setting in django will auto-convert UTC stored DB datetime into that timezone when django renders them in templates. I have it set to "UTC" right now, which is the default, and have been handling conversion for the user either in the front-end using moment, or manually in the view.

But I wish to use EST for all datetime in admin portal, but without making this the default for our regular users. Is this possible without changing TIME_ZONE? But at the same time, I don't want to manually convert this in every AdminModel/Form.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that [sets the current timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone) to `EST` for URLs in the admin domain. Something like:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin  # needed since Django 2.0
from django.utils.timezone import activate

class AdminTimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin): 
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith("/admin"):
            activate(pytz.timezone("EST"))
```

(Of course, hardcoding the URL like this isn't very DRY, but you get the idea.)

Comment: great idea, Kevin! I didn't think of that. I believe this is the answer, but will wait a few days to make sure no better answers come up.

Comment: `timezone.activate` needs the setting `USE_TZ = True`. Is there another way to make this work without changing the USE_TZ setting ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: There's no good way of doing that that I can think of. By setting `USE_TZ = False` you've opted out of letting Django handle timezones for you.

Answer (score 3):

Django has a new middleware system since Kevin's answer.

This should work in 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 2.0

```
import pytz
from django.utils.timezone import activate


class AdminTimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(self.process_request(request))
        return response

    @staticmethod
    def process_request(request):
        if request.path.startswith("/admin"):
            activate(pytz.timezone("EST"))
        return request
```

Comment: The use of `activate` requires the setting `USE_TZ = True` which is not always the case. I wonder if there is still a workaround.